Deployment not found error on deploying django project on cpanel
I have an issue in deploying my django project to cpanel after creating the python setup on cpanel pointing my subdomain to the setup project .I get 404(deployment not found) error once i click the url how can i fix that
i expect the project should show the passenger_wsgi.py IT Works Screen on click of the url
